# Javascript Document.bgColor does not work

Tags: javascript

In the below code, I get the two dialog boxes, but the bgColor of the page is never changed. Is there any standard that font / color changes are not honored in JavaScript ?

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>

<body bgColor="GRAY">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("This message is written by JavaScript");
alert('Am here');
alert('Am here again');
document.bgcolor="WHITE";
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bgColor` is really, really old. Better use CSS values. And you need to address the `body` element, not the document.

This should work: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'`

Comment: Awesome. I got this from a new book and was wondering how come this didnt work. I tried in Chrome, IE and FF. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 4):

That's because it's `bgColor` and not `bgcolor` (note the case).

Also, using `document.body.style.backgroundColor` might be a better idea. And I would use hexadecimal instead of named colors :)

So, use `#ffffff` instead of `WHITE`.

Comment: Your first sentence nails it(Camelback notation). Why use hex instead of named colors?

Comment: @barlop: it's easy to make mistakes with named colors. Typos, non-existing colors, etc... hex is (in my experience) less prone to errors.